# generate wld file for tiles

Tags: geoserver, gdal, tiles, image-mosaic

I have generated tiles using gdal_retile command. The tiles do not have wld file. 
Is there any way to generate a wld for each tile (bash processing is preferred since I have around 9K tiles stored).

Comment: why do you need them?

Comment: this is a good question, they should be discouraged :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding '-co WORLDFILE=YES' to the gdal_retile command, which on my system warns but does indeed create the '.wld' (from 'gdal_translate' in my tests, but should also work for 'gdal_retile').

As per http://gdal.org/gdal_retile.html and http://gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html it says you can set 'TFW=YES' and this will give '.tfw' - which you could rename to '.wld' easily enough.

```
 gdalinfo --version
 GDAL 2.1.1, released 2016/07/07
```

Answer (score 1):

The projection information will be embedded in the outputs, so you might not need them.  However, if you are using older software that requires a world file, you can use QGIS and go: `Raster->Projections->Extract projection`.  Select batch mode and proce the entire directory where your output files are stored.  That should save you re-processing the tiles (I'm geussing this will be quicker than re-issuing the gdal command as mdsummer correctly suggests).